# Serial upvoting reversed, can't really understand why

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

So, apparently the Stack Overflow script thinks I got someone or something (bot), that upvoted too many of my answers, and therefore I got serial voting reversed.

I don't have bots (TBH, I don't know how to create them) and I just know one guy in person from here, who barely comes here.

So is it my fault that I happen to have (apparently) some user who likes my answers (or even me - modesty apart), and upvotes a few of them in a row?

In which way is this considered serial upvoting?

I really noticed 5 to 6 upvotes in short time yesterday and before yesterday (as I noticed in the past); may this be a cause for that?

I never asked anyone to upvote my answers neither in the Stack Overflow 
community using comments, much more outside of the community.

**P.S**. - Does the script reverse also votes cast along time ago?? (Givin it runs in a daily-basis)

Because it just did to me (I just noticed that)

Does that means all this votes came from a user only?

Comment: If the serial voting script reverses it... Then yes, by definition,it's considered serial voting. Does that mean YOU are at fault? Nah

Comment: The script shouldn't reverse very old votes, but if the team was investigating someone's voting habits and found they serially voted for you, they can manually reverse older votes. May be what happened.

Comment: A single person voted for you 30+ times, with over 90% of their votes only going to you. These votes were cleaned up as part of a sweep through other troubling voting patterns. If moderators thought that you were connected to any of this, you'd be contacted by one of us.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not your fault, and *unless* the moderators have a *very convincing* indication that you're trying to fraud the system, you won't be penalized for being serially upvoted. I imagine this happens to Jon Skeet once every <s>week</s> day or so.

But that doesn't make the upvotes you received 'fair' upvotes. Therefore, they are reversed.